# Command Not Found when writing a Node Shell Script

Tags: shell, node.js, command-line

I am attempting to create a shell script using Node.js similar to packages like [express](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/bin/express) and [mocha](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/blob/master/bin/mocha).  My initial test reported command not found so I backed the script to the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log("printing stuff");
```

The above should just output "printing stuff" when ran; however, that too doesn't work.

I'm attempting to execute the script via `./script` in the directory of the file in order to ensure it's not a pathing issue.  Attempting to execute under a privileged state (i.e. sudo) yields the same results/error message.

Any idea what I need to do?

Comment: What happens when you `node -v` in the same dir?

Comment: I can also `npm install mocha` in the directory and call `./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha` without issue.

Comment: Odd, that should work. What OS?

Comment: @RyanOlds Mac OSX 10.7 (Lion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out my issue.  I made the shell script but forgot to set execute permissions onto the file.  doing a `chmod a+x script` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

When you shebang (`#!`) `/usr/bin/env node`, you are saying "look for a program called node on my PATH". If doing `node -v` works, as @Ryan says, the shebang should work fine. Any chance you have a shell alias or shell function named `node`? That could be giving you the illusion that your PATH is correct even when it is not. But essentially, just make sure the directory where the `node` binary lives (the `bin` directory under your node install) is on your PATH environment variable, and things really should work at that point.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/node/bin:$PATH
```